# creating a View within a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a fairly large ASP.NET MVC 2 project that has the Controllers separated into another project.  I would like to create a View within a parent View.

I have `ParentController` and `ChildController`, both inheriting from "Controller."  I would like to create a folder called "ChildController" within "ParentController"  and add Views from there.

Obviously, this throws a "The Resource could not be found" error.

Do I need to edit the controllers? Is this a routing limitation?

(How) can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, views checked in the Views/{ControllerPrefix} folder.  Then in the Views/Shared folder.

Your folder needs to match the controller's Prefix, ie:

```
ChildController
```

will pull views from

```
/views/child/
```

You can also directly reference the view based on it's application path from any controller:

```
~/views/child/subview.ascx
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but providing custom view search paths is done by writing a custom `ViewEngine` class.

But having multiple controllers (no matter how they're inherited) should always be a folder per controller in the `Views` folder.

I guess you're using `Html.RenderAction` method. Doesn't really matter. Your View folder structure should still be:

```
/Views
  /Parent
    /Index.aspx
    /Whatever.aspx
  /Child
    /SubView.ascx   <- this one here is a partial view if you use RenderAction()
```